# I need help slowing down a ball in SDL

Tags: int, sdl

I am making a "breakout" clone and right now the ball is moving too fast. To slow it down I tried to convert the variables into floats and use decimals, but then the ball didn't move at all.

Help me figure out how to slow down the ball.

```
//The headers
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

//The screen attributes
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1008;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

const int BALL_X = 500;
const int BALL_Y = 600;

Uint32 white;

//The surfaces
SDL_Surface *mainScreen = NULL;
SDL_Surface *difficultyScreen = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;

//The event structure
SDL_Event event;

//Rects
SDL_Rect Paddle;
SDL_Rect Ball;
SDL_Rect Block1;
SDL_Rect Block2;
SDL_Rect Block3;
SDL_Rect Block4;
SDL_Rect Block5;
SDL_Rect Block6;
SDL_Rect Block7;
SDL_Rect Block8;
SDL_Rect Block9;
SDL_Rect Block10;
SDL_Rect Block11;
SDL_Rect Block12;
SDL_Rect Block13;
SDL_Rect Block14;
SDL_Rect Block15;
SDL_Rect Block16;
SDL_Rect Block17;
SDL_Rect Block18;
SDL_Rect Block19;
SDL_Rect Block20;
SDL_Rect Block21;
SDL_Rect Block22;
SDL_Rect Block23;
SDL_Rect Block24;
SDL_Rect Block25;
SDL_Rect Block26;

int xVel, yVel;

bool PointInRect(int x, int y, SDL_Rect rec)
{
    if (x > rec.x && y > rec.y && x < rec.x + rec.w && y < rec.y + rec.h)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool CheckCollision(SDL_Rect r1, SDL_Rect r2)
{
    if (PointInRect(r1.x, r1.y, r2) == true ||
         PointInRect(r1.x + r1.w, r1.y, r2) == true ||
         PointInRect(r1.x, r1.y + r1.h, r2) == true ||
         PointInRect(r1.x + r1.w, r1.y + r1.h, r2) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


void ResetBall()
{
    Ball.x = BALL_X;
    Ball.y = BALL_Y;
    xVel = 1;
    yVel = 1;
}

void LoadGame()
{
    Paddle.x = 425;
    Paddle.y = 650;
    Paddle.h = 20;
    Paddle.w = 150;

    Ball.x = BALL_X;
    Ball.y = BALL_Y;
    Ball.h = 15;
    Ball.w = 15;

    Block1.x = 58;
    Block1.y = 28;
    Block1.h = 15;
    Block1.w = 100;

    Block2.x = 216;
    Block2.y = 28;
    Block2.h = 15;
    Block2.w = 100;

    Block3.x = 374;
    Block3.y = 28;
    Block3.h = 15;
    Block3.w = 100;

    Block4.x = 533;
    Block4.y = 28;
    Block4.h = 15;
    Block4.w = 100;

    Block5.x = 691;
    Block5.y = 28;
    Block5.h = 15;
    Block5.w = 100;

    Block6.x = 849;
    Block6.y = 28;
    Block6.h = 15;
    Block6.w = 100;

    Block7.x = 84;
    Block7.y = 71;
    Block7.h = 15;
    Block7.w = 100;

    Block8.x = 269;
    Block8.y = 71;
    Block8.h = 15;
    Block8.w = 100;

    Block9.x = 453;
    Block9.y = 71;
    Block9.h = 15;
    Block9.w = 100;

    Block10.x = 638;
    Block10.y = 71;
    Block10.h = 15;
    Block10.w = 100;

    Block11.x = 822;
    Block11.y = 71;
    Block11.h = 15;
    Block11.w = 100;

    Block12.x = 23;
    Block12.y = 114;
    Block12.h = 15;
    Block12.w = 100;

    Block13.x = 146;
    Block13.y = 114;
    Block13.h = 15;
    Block13.w = 100;

    Block14.x = 269;
    Block14.y = 114;
    Block14.h = 15;
    Block14.w = 100;

    Block15.x = 392;
    Block15.y = 114;
    Block15.h = 15;
    Block15.w = 100;

    Block16.x = 516;
    Block16.y = 114;
    Block16.h = 15;
    Block16.w = 100;

    Block17.x = 639;
    Block17.y = 114;
    Block17.h = 15;
    Block17.w = 100;

    Block18.x = 762;
    Block18.y = 114;
    Block18.h = 15;
    Block18.w = 100;

    Block19.x = 885;
    Block19.y = 114;
    Block19.h = 15;
    Block19.w = 100;

    Block20.x = 88;
    Block20.y = 157;
    Block20.h = 15;
    Block20.w = 100;

    Block21.x = 820;
    Block21.y = 157;
    Block21.h = 15;
    Block21.w = 100;

    Block22.x = 138;
    Block22.y = 200;
    Block22.h = 15;
    Block22.w = 100;

    Block23.x = 296;
    Block23.y = 200;
    Block23.h = 15;
    Block23.w = 100;

    Block24.x = 454;
    Block24.y = 200;
    Block24.h = 15;
    Block24.w = 100;

    Block25.x = 612;
    Block25.y = 200;
    Block25.h = 15;
    Block25.w = 100;

    Block26.x = 770;
    Block26.y = 200;
    Block26.h = 15;
    Block26.w = 100;

    white = SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 255, 255);

    srand(time(NULL));

    ResetBall();
}
void Logic()
{
    SDL_Event occur;
    SDL_PollEvent(&occur);
    Uint8 *keystates = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
    if (keystates[SDLK_LEFT])
    {
        Paddle.x -= 1;
    }
    if (keystates[SDLK_RIGHT])
    {
        Paddle.x += 1;
    }
    if (Paddle.x < 1)
    {
        Paddle.x = 1;
    }
    if (Paddle.x + Paddle.w > 1007)
    {
        Paddle.x = 1007 - Paddle.w;
    }

    //For ball movement
    Ball.x += xVel;
    Ball.y += yVel;

    //Change the direction of the ball if ball hits the walls
    if (Ball.y < 1)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
    }
    if (Ball.y + Ball.h > 1007)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
    }
    if (Ball.x < 1)
    {
        xVel = -xVel;
    }
    if (Ball.x + Ball.w > 1007)
    {
        xVel = -xVel;
    }


    //Change the direction of the ball if ball hits the paddle
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Paddle) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
    }

    //Change the direction of the ball if ball hits the blocks
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block1) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block1.x = -200;
        Block1.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block2) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block2.x = -200;
        Block2.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block3) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block3.x = -200;
        Block3.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block4) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block4.x = -200;
        Block4.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block5) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block5.x = -200;
        Block5.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block6) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block6.x = -200;
        Block6.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block7) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block7.x = -200;
        Block7.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block8) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block8.x = -200;
        Block8.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block9) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block9.x = -200;
        Block9.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block10) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block10.x = -200;
        Block10.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block11) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block11.x = -200;
        Block11.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block12) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block12.x = -200;
        Block12.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block13) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block13.x = -200;
        Block13.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block14) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block14.x = -200;
        Block14.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block15) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block15.x = -200;
        Block15.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block16) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block16.x = -200;
        Block16.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block17) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block17.x = -200;
        Block17.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block18) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block18.x = -200;
        Block18.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block19) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block19.x = -200;
        Block19.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block20) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block20.x = -200;
        Block20.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block21) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block21.x = -200;
        Block21.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block22) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block22.x = -200;
        Block22.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block23) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block23.x = -200;
        Block23.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block24) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block24.x = -200;
        Block24.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block25) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block25.x = -200;
        Block25.y = -200;
    }
    if (CheckCollision(Ball, Block26) == true)
    {
        yVel = -yVel;
        Block26.x = -200;
        Block26.y = -200;
    }
}

//Function to load image
SDL_Surface *load_Image( std::string filename )
{
    //Temporary storage for the image that's loaded
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;

    //The optimized image that will be used
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;
    loadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP(filename.c_str());

    //If nothing went wrong in loading the image
    if(loadedImage != NULL)
    {
        //Create an optimized image
        optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(loadedImage);

        //Free the old surface
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    }
    //Return the optimized image
    return optimizedImage;
}
//Function to apply picture to screen
void apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination, SDL_Rect* clip = NULL)
{
    //Holds offsets
    SDL_Rect offset;

    //Get offsets
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;

    //Blit
    SDL_BlitSurface(source, clip, destination, &offset);
}
//Function to start SDL
bool init()
{
    //Initialize all SDL subsystems
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) == -1 )
    {
        return false;
    }
    //set up the screen
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE );

    //If there was an error in setting up the screen
    if( screen == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Name the window
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( "Block Breaker", NULL );

    //If everything initialized fine
    return true;
}
//Function to load files
bool load_files()
{
    //Load the image
    mainScreen = load_Image( "Menu.bmp" );
    difficultyScreen = load_Image( "Speed Menu.bmp" );
    return true;
}
//function to stop SDL
void clean_up()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(mainScreen);
    SDL_FreeSurface(difficultyScreen);
    SDL_FreeSurface(screen);

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();
}
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{

    //Variables
    bool running = true;
    bool menu = true;
    bool difficulty = false;
    bool mediumGame = false;
    bool hardGame = false;
    bool quit = false;

    //Initialize
    if ( init() == false )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //Quit function
    if (quit == true)
    {
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    //Load the files
    if ( load_files() == false )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    LoadGame();
    //while the user hasn't quit
    while (quit == false)
    {
        //Menu screen
        if (menu==true)
        {
            //Apply screen
            apply_surface(0,0,mainScreen,screen);

            //Loop to handle input by user
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                if (event.type==SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
                {
                    if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                    {
                        int x = event.button.x;
                        int y = event.button.y;
                        //Button for difficulty screen
                        if ((x>370)&&(x<660)&&(y>265)&&(y<370))
                        {
                            menu = false;
                            difficulty = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }
                        if ((x>374)&&(x<660)&&(y>390)&&(y<500))
                        {
                            menu = false;
                            quit = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }
                    }
                SDL_Flip(screen);
                }
                else if (event.type==SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
            SDL_Flip(screen);
        }

        //Difficulty screen
        else if (difficulty==true)
        {
            //Apply surface
            apply_surface(0,0,difficultyScreen,screen);
            SDL_Flip(screen);

            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                if (event.type==SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
                {
                    if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                    {
                        int x = event.button.x;
                        int y = event.button.y;
                        //Button for medium game screen
                        if ((x>360)&&(x<660)&&(y>370)&&(y<465))
                        {
                            difficulty = false;
                            mediumGame = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }
                        //Button for hard game screen
                        if ((x>420)&&(x<610)&&(y>490)&&(y<575))
                        {
                            difficulty = false;
                            hardGame = true;
                            SDL_Flip(screen);
                        }
                    }
                SDL_Flip(screen);
                }
                else if (event.type==SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //Medium game screen
        else if (mediumGame == true)
        {
            //Fill color
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0x68, 0x68, 0x68 ));

            //Logic for the game
            Logic();

            //Place Paddle
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Paddle, white);

            //Place Ball
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Ball, white);

            //Place Blocks
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block1, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block2, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block3, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block4, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block5, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block6, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block7, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block8, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block9, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block10, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block11, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block12, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block13, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block14, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block15, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block16, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block17, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block18, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block19, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block20, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block21, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block22, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block23, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block24, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block25, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block26, white);

            //Flip screen
            SDL_Flip(screen);
        }

        //Hard game screen
        else if (hardGame == true)
        {
            //Fill color
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0x68, 0x68, 0x68 ));

            //Logic for the game
            Logic();

            //Place Paddle
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Paddle, white);

            //Place Ball
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Ball, white);

            //Place Blocks
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block1, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block2, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block3, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block4, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block5, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block6, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block7, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block8, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block9, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block10, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block11, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block12, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block13, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block14, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block15, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block16, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block17, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block18, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block19, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block20, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block21, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block22, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block23, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block24, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block25, white);
            SDL_FillRect(screen, &Block26, white);

            //Flip screen
            SDL_Flip(screen);
        }
    }

    //Clean up
    clean_up();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Use floats for the ball position.

Using floats for velocity is the right thing to do if you think you'll need to adjust the speed with finer precision than the integer pixel resolution of the screen.  The reason the ball didn't move at all when you used floating point velocities is because you are not using floating point *positions*.

Here's an example:

```
int x = 4;
float velx = 0.05f;
x += velx;
```

What value is x going to have?  The same value as this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    x += velx;
```

`x` is not changing because it can only ever be an integer and the decimal value is truncated when stored as an integer.  Change `x` to a float for this to work properly.  In your case, don't use SDL_Rect (which is 4 ints) to store the position of objects.  Create your own class/struct that uses floats.